# Linux mint files color changed in terminal

Tags: ssh, files, linux-mint, terminal, rsync

I am using Linux Minter 19.0 on two machines.

I have a src and destination folder.

My src folder is on my local machine, and the dest folder is on a remote machine.

I ran rsync to move files from src to dest over ssh.

After I open two terminals. One on the local machine viewing src folder. The other terminal is viewing the dest folder on the remote machine over ssh.

When I run ls command in the two folders, the files colorings in the different terminals are different.

Why is this, and what does this mean?

Why are the same files different color in the two terminals? For example out.wav is green in one and blue in the  other.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File colors in Linux, tell you things about the file that the extension if it even has one might or might not.

- Blue: Directory
- Green: Executable or recognized data file
- Sky Blue: Symbolic link file
- Yellow with black background: Device
- Pink: Graphic image file
- Red: Archive file
- Red with black background: Broken link

The colors can be changed in your .bashrc like DIR 01;34 for directories, this should be stock. Changing them is as easy as adjusting the numbers, formatting is done like what is seen above 01;34 and more information on color numbering can be found: [Here](https://www.networkworld.com/article/3269587/linux/customizing-your-text-colors-on-the-linux-command-line.html)

More information on changing colors can be found: [Here](https://serverfault.com/a/463793/496863)

The differences you are seeing is more than likely a result of the colorscheme on the remote machine. More information on this principle idea can be found: [Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/414395/321418)

Comment: This answer does not address my specific scenario. Why do my same file types differ in color?

Comment: Just updated my answer.

Comment: Why is the same file different colors in the different terminals?

Comment: Because the colorschemes are different.

Comment: How. They are both the exact same terminal application on the same machine sharing the same settings. That would not be possible.

Comment: If your ssh'd into a remote machine then the color scheme of that machine is what you should be seeing. I know that my vim example is not ideal but it is the same principle.